# Very difficult to grab YUV buffer after picture taken

Tags: android, camera, image

I am trying to implement a camera app, but it looks only the onJepgTaken in PictureCallback can take a buffer, while onRaw and onPostView takes null. And getSupportedPictureFormats always returns 256, so no hope to get YUV directly. If this is the case, I guess if I want to process the large image after image taking, I can only get the jpeg decoder for processing.
Updated: seems NV16 is available in takepicture callback and even if YUV buffer is not available, libjpeg is still there for codec stuff.